# Assign Service Account or IAM role to Google Compute Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I use AWS Instance based IAM roles extensively in AWS, but I am unable to find the equivalent in the web console for Google Compute.

I wish to establish IAM roles and assign them to Google Compute Engine instances to allow scripts to automatically update labels, etc. but I am unable to locate how to do this, or how to assign/change account/role for Google Compute Instances.

Am I missing something, or is this functionality not supported ?

Comment: Google Cloud compute service use service accounts. Compute Engine, for example, has a default service account to all instances. You can assign/modify the roles assigned to a service account.  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts

Comment: But, is there a way to make a service account unique to an instance, then assign roles to that service account? If so, where do you see the service account settings per instance in the console?

Comment: You can create a service account with required roles and then assign that service account to one or several instances. When you create a VM instances, you have the option of selecting the service account to assign to the instance.

Comment: Can you change the instance service account once the instance is live, or does it need to happen at instance creation.

Comment: You can change the service account after creation.

Comment: Just to add to John's comment - you can also create a custom role (with exact IAM permissions you need), and assign it to any (number) of service accounts.